# Visual Studio 2013 scrolling issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I am scrolling on editor I've got wired visual effect. Look at the pic
[image]

It is a cache overflow? What is wrong with visual studio 2013? I restart the computer, but nothing help.

Comment: Have you installed updates?

Comment: Try updating your graphics driver.

Comment: I installed all available updates. Nothing help.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize the question would close from just my vote :( I would uninstall all extensions, and disable hardware acceleration in the options.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is highly likely to be a graphics driver problem, try upgrading your driver for your graphics card.
If you have an Nvidia, AMD or an Intel graphic processor, I recommend you follow the next link: http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/36254

Comment: I update the intel graphics driver but it does not help.